# Is it possible to highlight every cell with counters `iRow `and `jCol` in `NiceTabular`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, highlighting, nicematrix

It is very common for me to need to place braces in matrix environment in a controlled fashion which I find `NiceTabular` environment suitable for such purpose.

One difficulty I encounter is that when tables are very large in size, it becomes harder to determine the position of each cell in the table. Is it possible to systematically highlight the cells numbers using the counters `iRow` and `jCol` as follows?

[image]

The following requirements are to be met

1. The highlighting color and transparency should be controllable
2. Highlighting should go exactly in the middle of each cell (even when `\Block` environment is used, cells of the `\Block` should still be highlighted)
3. If possible, the highlighting should be done using a convenient key to be added in the options

My MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\widthCell}
\newcommand{\phantombox}[2]{%
    \setlength{\widthCell}{\widthof{{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}}}%
    {#2}\llap{\parbox{\widthCell}{\centering\color{gray!25}#1}}%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,rules/color=[gray]{0.89},rules/width=0.2pt]{*{3}c}
    
    \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
    \\
    
    \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
    \\
    
    \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & \phantombox{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}{Cell \arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
    \\
    
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{\{}{1-1}{3-1}{.}
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-2}{2-2}{\}}
    
    
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer if it solved the problem. The same is true for some of your other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \HighLight { O { } }
  {
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\arabic{iRow}}
      \foreach \j in {1,...,\arabic{jCol}}
        { 
          \tikz [remember~picture, overlay] 
            \node [opacity=0.5] at (\i.5-|\j.5) { \Large \color{red} \i , \j } ;
        }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\Block{2-2}{test} &           & test \\
                  &           & blabla \\
test              & some text & nothing 
\CodeAfter \HighLight
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to add such highlighting as an option in a future version of `nicematrix`, it would be very helpful when building large tables

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh: I have written a new version with such feature (see other answer).

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (version 6.9 of 2022/05/25), there is a command `\ShowCellNames` available in the `\CodeAfter` and the `\CodeBefore` to address your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\Block{2-2}{} &           & test \\
                  &           & blabla \\
              & some text & nothing 
\CodeAfter \ShowCellNames
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]