# How to allow for guided braces placement using nicematrix?

Tags: nicematrix

In a previous question ([Is it possible to highlight every cell with counters `iRow` and `jCol` in `NiceTabular`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622576/is-it-possible-to-highlight-every-cell-with-counters-irow-and-jcol-in-nicet)), I asked for easy way to highlight cell nodes. As a result of my question F. Pantigny (the author of `nicematrix` package) added a new command `\ShowCellNames`. However, the implementation of this command in the package may be improved as follows

1. The command highlights cell nodes in red color. It is possible for the color to be determined by the user with an option as `[color]{transperancy}`. The defaults of the package are good. However, I think that blending red with white is better (`[red!75]{0}`)
2. The command highlights cells nodes and places the contents as transparent in the background. It is possible to add new option such as `[content/transparency=value, content/background=color]` and which allows the user to control the visibility of the main contents. The defaults of the package are good `[content/transparency=0.75, content/background=white]`
3. The separator between rows and columns numbering should be customizable for convenience such as `[ij-sep=separator]`. I recommend a default of `[ij-sep=, $\mspace{\thinmuskip}$]`
4. The command should also have the option to enable faded `hvlines` for ease of editing such as `[hvlines, rules/color=[gray]{0.75}]` which should be available to enable as option of `\ShowCellNames` (not only the table options)
5. The package itself should have an option such as `ShowCellNames=<true or false>` which allows for enabling cell names for all matrices. This enables easy debuging and tuning
6. It is possible to add an option `[ij-font=style]` to specify how the font itself should appear. I recommend a default of `[ij-font=\normalfont \Large \bfseries]`
7. The package should have an option such as `CellNamesReverese=<true or false>`. This allows for providing no transparency for the main content and getting the cell numbering transparency to be `0.75`

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{e}{@{$\mspace{\thickmuskip}$}c@{$\mspace{\thickmuskip}$}}

\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \everymath{\displaystyle}
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0mm}
    \begin{NiceArray}[cell-space-limits=3.7pt]{@{}r e @{\quad}l}
        f(x) &= x + 1 &
        \\
        g(x) &= x + 2 &
        \\
        h(x) &= x + 3 & \Block[l]{3-1}{\text{Text for $h(x)$,} \\ \text{$k(x)$, and $k(x)$}}
        \\
        k(x) &= x + 4 &
        \\
        l(x) &= x + 5 &
        \CodeAfter
        \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{2-2}{\}}[extra-height=-1.1pt]
        \SubMatrix{.}{3-2}{5-2}{\}}[extra-height=-1.1pt]
        \ShowCellNames
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```